# How to monitor if a BigQuery table contains current data and send an alert if not?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, monitoring

I have a BigQuery table and an external data import process that should add entries every day. I need to verify that the table contains current data (with a timestamp of today). Writing the SQL-query is not a problem.

My question is how to best install such a monitoring in GCP? Can Stackdriver execute custom BigQuery SQL? Or would a CloudFunction be more suitable? An AppEngine application with a cronjob? What's the best practise?

Comment: How do you write in BigQuery? Do you perform a load job? Do you stream write? Is only a query can validate the data completion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what's the best practice here, but one simple solution is to use BigQuery scheduled query. Schedule query, make it fail is something is wrong using [ERROR() function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/debugging_functions), configure scheduled query to notify (it sends email) if it fails.

Comment: A short and simple solution that exactly fits my needs, thank you!